# Truncate and cast into varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a number I'm trying to cast into a varchar, and I don't care if it gets truncated.

My problem is that I keep getting these errors, depending on what I try:

> String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> Arithmetic overflow error for type varchar, value = 0.000052

Here is my current attempts:

```
declare @a as varchar(10), @b as varchar(10), @c as varchar(10)

set @a =cast(@b as float) / cast(@c as float)

DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
  [read] varchar(20), 
  [percent] varchar(10)
)
insert into @temp ([read],[percent])
  VALUES('text', @a)
```

I've also tried some of the following for the second line:

```
set @a = cast( cast(@b as float) / cast(@c as float) as varchar())
```

One oddity is that it works some of the time, but not all of the time.  I've been able to discover that it only works when `@a` is large enough and not negative.  When it is either negative or small, I get some of the above errors.

Comment: I edited your query. You posted a query with errors, you forgot keywords for declaring a table and inserting a value. But you were asking a different error question :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing it up.  I had to type the code with names different from what I'm working with, and am prone to errors.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert floating point numbers to characters strings, I highly recommend the `str()` function, which is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

In your case, it would look something like:

```
set @a = str( cast(@b as float) / cast(@c as float), 10, 4)
```

where `10` and `4` are whatever scale and precision that you want.

By the way, when using `varchar()` in SQL, you should always include a length.  Do not depend on the defaults, because they can change depending on where the expression is used.

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to figure that out for such a long time, and the answer was so simple.